# Dynamically set Ranges to the columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am importing some date to worksheet which needs to be ranged for validation and reference in other worksheets.

Say I have 4 columns in worksheet(WS1) but the row count is dynamic on every import. How can i range the columns(A:D)?

Please help.

Regards,
Mani

Answer (score 1):

Use a lastRow variable to determine the last row.  I included a few examples of this.  Also on this example is a lastCol variable..  You can use this if the number of Columns is dynamic as well.

```
Private Sub lastRow()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim sheet As String

    sheet = "WS1"

    lastRow = Sheets(sheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row   'Using Range()
    lastRow = Sheets(sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row    'Using Cells()

    lastCol = Sheets(sheet).Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Sub
```

You can loop through your sheet easily enough using variables also.  Using Cells(row,col) instead of Range(A1). you can use numbers or a letter in quotes for the column as shown in the example.

This example looks at WS1 and matches someValue.  If the value in Column A of WS1 = somevalue, the record is copied to a "Master" Sheet.

```
Sub LoopExample()
Dim mRow As Long  'used for a master row
    For lRow = 2 To lastRow
        If Sheets(sheet).Cells(lRow, 1) = someValue Then
            'perform something here like this.  Copy columns A:D to the Master Sheet if match
            For lCol = 1 To 4   'or you could go 1 to lastCol if you needed it dynamic
                Sheets("MASTER").Cells(mRow, lCol) = Sheets(sheet).Cells(lRow, lCol) 'mRow as Row on Master
            Next lCol
            mRow = mRow + 1   'Increment the Master Row
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree  with PJ, just to add one more method of finding lastrow if you dont want to hard code a specific column
`lastrow = Sheet("sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: Be careful using `UsedRange` to get the last used row on a sheet: if there are no values in (e.g.) Row 1 then that row doesn't count towards `UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyways. But what i wanted was just to Name ranges the columns in worksheet.

I have already accomplished the copy and paste (Loading data b/w worksheets).

This is what i wanted.

```
vRowCount = DestWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
vColCount = DestWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

DestWorkSheet.usedRange.Columns.AutoFit
AddNamedRange Dest_RATES, DATA_Dest_RATES
```

Where AddNamedRange is a function,

```
    Public Sub AddNamedRange(ByVal sheetCodeName As String, ByVal namedRange As String)
    Dim rngToBeNamed As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

   On Error GoTo AddNamedRange_Error

   Set rngToBeNamed = GetUsedRange(sheetCodeName)
   Set ws = rngToBeNamed.Worksheet
   ws.Names.Add name:=namedRange, RefersTo:=ws.Range(rngToBeNamed.Address)

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub


  AddNamedRange_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure AddNamedRange of Module     UtilitiesRange"

    End Sub
```

Regards,

Mani

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could just use something like this in the sheet module:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
        Dim i As Long
        Dim NamesOfNames(1 To 4) As String

            NamesOfNames(1) = "NameOfColumn1"
            NamesOfNames(2) = "NameOfColumn2"   
            NamesOfNames(3) = "NameOfColumn3"
            NamesOfNames(4) = "NameOfColumn4" 

        For i = 1 To 4
            ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=NamesOfNames(i), _ 
                RefersTo:=Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row, i))
        Next i
    End Sub
```